# How to get MQSeries queuename in .NET without 2068

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, ibm-mq

I have a generic 'datapump' that is running is part of a Windows service; an instance of it exists for each queue that I'm monitoring for new incoming messages from an MQSeries queue. 
If the Get method fails, I want to be able to show the name of the queue, so I'm trying to build a debug variable that can be used in the catch handler.  I'm getting a 2068 MQRC_SELECTOR_NOT_FOR_TYPE on the line that sets debugQueueInfo below.

```
    debugLocation = "queueGetName";
    debugQueueInfo = "Queue:" + queueIn.RemoteQueueManagerName + ":"
                          + queueIn.RemoteQueueName;

    debugLocation = "queueGetMessage";
    queueIn.Get(mqMessage, mqGetMessageOptions);
```

How can I get the current queue manager name, and queue name?  The variable queueIn is of type IMB.WMQ.MQQueue, and I'm using the .NET API.

When the queue was object was built, I used the following:

```
queueOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_BROWSE; 
MQQueue mqQueue = qmgr.AccessQueue(mqCloneSpecs.queueName, queueOptions);
```

Based on the doc of the error code for 2068, I thought maybe adding the MQC.MQOO_BROWSE would fix the issue, but it did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RemoteQueueManagerName and RemoteQueueName are valid for remote queues only. I think that's the reason why you are getting 2068. MQOO_BROWSE otpion is for getting a message without removing it from the queue.

You can use `Name` property to get the queue name, like

```
debugQueueInfo = "Queue:" + queueIn.Name;
```

`MQQueue` class does not have a property to get the queue manager name. You will have to get it from MQQueueManager instance.